# Regular Expression Matching for number only with 2 digits repeated

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match number which are having 2 digits and those are repeated and the length of number is 7 digits .

I want to match these numbers from java .

example numbers:

```
3433434
6776767
9000999
```

Please help to create the regular expression for these pattern numbers

Comment: Ideally, you provide your own attempt first.

Comment: On that matter, I'm not sure RegEx will help you, as you have about 90 possibilities

Comment: What is the expected output for the example numbers?

Comment: Please provide what you would expect to get from 'example numbers'

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend hiding any regexes inside helper methods:

```
private static boolean matchesCriteria(String s) {
    return exactlySevenDigits(s) && containsRepeatedDigits(s);
}

private static boolean exactlySevenDigits(String s) {
    return s.matches("\\d{7}");
}

private static boolean containsRepeatedDigits(String s) {
    return s.matches(".*(\\d)\\1.*");
}
```

Example results:

```
3433434  true
6776767  true
9000999  true
1234567  false    (no repeating numbers)
12331233 false    (too long)
123356A  false    (not all digits)
```

Answer (score 1):

With regex it is a little complicated, I would use this way (Java 8+) instead :

```
boolean check = myString.chars()
                .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                .size() == 2;
```

---

The idea is to create a Set with the character of this string, if the size of the Set is 2 then it is correct String else it is not.

---

Or as **Ralf Renz** mention in comment, you can use this short way :

```
boolean check = myString.chars().distinct().count() == 2;
```

---

So your final solution should look like this :

```
boolean check = myString.matches("\\d{7}") && myString.chars().distinct().count() == 2;
```

Comment: myString.chars().distinct().count()==2 is shorter.

Comment: this is correct @RalfRenz I mentioned you in my answer, thank you :)

Comment: This solves the problem but doesn't really answer the specific question about how to use regular expressions to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes @ᴇʟᴇvᴀтᴇ I agree with you, there are many ways, one of them is this, simple than the regex and in term of performance I think regex is slow

Comment: I'm not really a believer of early optimization. I think if you hide the implementation details away behind well-named methods, you can always tweak or reimplement them for performance later, if you need to. You could precompile the regex patterns, for example, and then they'll be pretty fast. Anyway you're still using regex!  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
String str = "3433434";
boolean sevenOf2Digits = str.length() == 7 &&
                         str.matches("(\\d)\\1*+(\\d)(\\1|\\2)*");
System.out.println(sevenOf2Digits);
```

The first `(\\d)` captures the first digit in group 1.

`\\1` is a backreference to group 1, so the first digit. `*` is 0 or more of those digits, `+` makes that possessive, which is required to prevent the next `(\\d)` from matching the same digit.

The following `(\\d)` captures the second digit in group 2.

`(\\1|\\2)*` just matches 0 or more of any combination of the first or second digits.

---

I separated out the length check for simplicity. If you want a pure regex solution, you can add the length check to your regex in the form of a lookahead by adding `(?=.{7}$)` to the start of your regex.

```
"(?=.{7}$)(\\d)\\1*+(\\d)(\\1|\\2)*"
```

Comment: For real-world applications, if you're running Java 8+, I'd probably recommend the non-regex `string.chars().distinct().count()`, [as YCF_L / Ralf Renz recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50024743/1711796), since that's much more readable (assuming a regex isn't specifically required).

Answer (score 0):

`(?=^.{7}$)(\d)\1*(?!\1)(\d)(?:\1|\2)*`

This should do it. It finds a digit and repeats, then finds a second digit and repeats. Then it checks if the rest of the number is one of those 2.

I'll explain in detail what this does.

`(?=^.{7}$)`: Before starting, make sure there are 7 characters between the start and end. If shorter or longer, fast fails.

`(\d)\1*(?!\1)(\d)`: Get the first digit and save it in a capture group. Then matches if the captured digit is also the next one. If there is only a single digit, the next part will catch that. Last digit should always be different then the first one.

`(?:\1|\2)`: repeat the 2 captured digits 0 or more times.

Comment: but it is working for 1111111111 and there is no length limit

Comment: I've been continuously editing it because I've found those issues as well. I added `(?=^\d{7}$)` to limit it to 7 characters. I also added a negative lookahead after the first \1

Answer (score -1):

```
    String regex = "[10]{7}|[20]{7}|[21]{7}|[30]{7}|[31]{7}|[32]{7}|[40]{7}|[41]{7}|[42]{7}|[43]{7}|[50]{7}|[51]{7}|[52]{7}|[53]{7}|[54]{7}|[60]{7}|[61]{7}|[62]{7}|[63]{7}|[64]{7}|[65]{7}|[70]{7}|[71]{7}|[72]{7}|[73]{7}|[74]{7}|[75]{7}|[76]{7}|[80]{7}|[81]{7}|[82]{7}|[83]{7}|[84]{7}|[85]{7}|[86]{7}|[87]{7}|[90]{7}|[91]{7}|[92]{7}|[93]{7}|[94]{7}|[95]{7}|[96]{7}|[97]{7}|[98]{7}";

    System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regex, "3433434"));
    System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regex, "6776767"));
    System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regex, "9000999"));
```

That should do it. All combinations of two digits with a length of 7.

Comment: can't we simplify this is very long pattern